# How to display p:outputLabel in a p:datatable header?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

My Current Code is

```
<p:dataTable>    
 <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="1"width="10%" headerText="JustanExample">
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
 </p:columnGroup>
</p:dataTable>
```

This is okay. Works fine. **BUT**

I Want to write code as:

```
<p:dataTable>    
 <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="1"width="10%">
           <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red"></p:outputLabel>
           <p:outputLabel value="MandatoryColumnName"></p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
 </p:columnGroup>
</p:dataTable>
```

But this gives me a blank header in the datatable, where as I want ***MandatoryColumnName** (where color of * is red)

Any Idea how to achive this?

Comment: So an `h:outputText` works? And did you check the PrimeFaces showcase?

Comment: I have checked with Primefaces Showcase. No help. And also, h:outputText instead of p:outputLabel also did not work

Comment: So your problem is more generic. The datatable showcase hasxa link to the documentation https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable. First code you see in there has a hint

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.